# bash echo command -e arguments ignored using echo full path

Tags: bash, echo

What's happening here :

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo -e "foo"
foo
$ which echo
/bin/echo
$ /bin/echo -e "foo"
-e foo
```

The last output is expected to be "foo", like when using `echo` directly.

Comment: Then to be sure it's the bash builtin echo that is executed : `bash echo -e "foo"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/bin/echo` is a program, and it's different from the Bash built-in `echo` command.

According to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html), `echo` should not take any arguments. The Bash `echo` command doesn't follow this standard, and the GNU Coreutils version doesn't either. Other versions may be more strict.

Try to find out what version `/bin/echo` is by calling it with the `--version` flag or see if it gives you some help with the `--help` flag.

---

Also, `man which` shows this:

> **which** returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed
>   in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  commands  in a
>   strictly POSIX-conformant shell.

Bash is *not* strictly POSIX-conformant so the return value of `which` may differ (and it does in this case because of the `echo` built-in).

---

For further reading, see the answers to [echo outputs -e parameter in bash scripts. How can I prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435853/echo-outputs-e-parameter-in-bash-scripts-how-can-i-prevent-this?rq=1)

Comment: However, `type echo` displays "echo is a shell builtin". (At least for me.)