# How to force os.system() to use bash instead of shell

Tags: python, bash, python-2.4

I've tried what's told in [How to force /bin/bash interpreter for oneliners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906073/how-to-force-bin-bash-interpreter-for-oneliners)

By doing

```
os.system('GREPDB="my command"')
os.system('/bin/bash -c \'$GREPDB\'')
```

However no luck, unfortunately I need to run this command with bash and subp isn't an option in this environment, I'm limited to python 2.4.  Any suggestions to get me in the right direction?

Comment: Why the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/module-subprocess.html) is not an option? It is supported in Python 2.4.

Comment: pretty sure it is in 2.4.6, however this is 2.4.3

Comment: What about one of the various [`exec*`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execl) functions?

Comment: Putting a shell command in a shell variable is almost always completely the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both commands are executed in different subshells.

Setting variables in the first `system` call does not affect the second `system` call.

You need to put two command in one string (combining them with `;`).

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('GREPDB="echo 123"; /bin/bash -c "$GREPDB"')
123
0
```

**NOTE** You need to use `"$GREPDB"` instead of `'$GREPDBS'`. Otherwise it is interpreted literally instead of being expanded.

If you can use `subprocess`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('/bin/bash -c "$GREPDB"', shell=True,
...                 env={'GREPDB': 'echo 123'})
123
0
```

Comment: unfortunately this is still giving me shell errors :-(

Comment: @0n35, Could you post the traceback ?

Answer (score 8):

The solution below still initially invokes a shell, but it switches to bash for the command you are trying to execute:

```
os.system('/bin/bash -c "echo hello world"')
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
subprocess.call(["bash","-c",cmd])
```

//OK, ignore this because I have not notice subprocess not considered.

Comment: Please explain a little more. How does it work? Why is it a workaround?

Comment: @Stibu actually it is a workaround to fix my issue in windows msysgit environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Comment: `Popen` merely *starts* a process; you should manage the resulting object yourself. Of course, you can just use `subprocess.run()` instead, which does all of this plumbing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I searched this command for some days and found really working code:

```
import subprocess

def bash_command(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd])

code="abcde"
// you can use echo options such as -e
bash_command('echo -ne "'+code+'"')
```

Output:

```
abcde
```

Comment: `echo` in particular isn't a very good example; you should prefer `printf`. Though I suppose this would work if your specific question was "how can I use Bash's built-in `echo` from Python?"