# Error running bash for loop in python code

Tags: python, bash

I wanted to use the following command to run bash `for` loop inside my python code but it does not work ant gives the error :

```
os.system("for f in *.sam ; do samtools flagstat $f > ${f/.sam/.stat};done ")
```

and error is

> File "", line 1
>       os.system("for f in *.sam ; do samtools flagstat $f > ${f/.sam/.stat};done ")
>       ^

How can I use bash `for` loop inside the python code?

Comment: If you want to use `bash` features, make sure you use `bash`... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769039/2836621

Comment: Please show the entire error, including the type of error. Format it properly so that it is clear where the trailing ``^`` points to.

Comment: The error message looks like it's coming from Python, but I cant't repro. Did you have incorrect indentation, or perhaps an unmached quote or parenthesis on a previous line?

Comment: Also, you added the missing `done` in the question but it's still missing from the error message. I'm voting to close as unclear and unreproducible; see also the guidance for posting a [mre].

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use a Bash feature (`${variable/pattern/substitution}`) in `sh` code. You could use `subprocess.run` with `executable='/bin/bash'` but there is actually absolutely no reason to run the loop in the shell.

```
import glob
import subprocess

for file in glob.glob('*.sam'):
    with open(file.replace('.sam', '.stat'), 'w') as output:
        subprocess.run(['samtools', 'flagstat', file],
            stdout=output, check=True)
```

The `check=True` is assuming that `samtools` returns a useful exit code, and that you want to know if it fails.

Generally speaking, you should run as little code as possible in a `subprocess` because it's basically happening outside of your control. The parts you write yourself in Python (or better yet `import` from a well-maintained library) can be properly managed by your Python code, whereas the communications with an external process will necessarily be limitede and constrained.

Maybe see also [Running Bash commands from Python](/a/51950538/874188) for why to avoid `os.system` and the precise meaning of `check=True`, and [Difference between sh and bash](/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash). [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) explains why you want to avoid invoking a shell if you can.

For completeness' sake, here is a syntactically correct, `sh`-compatible `for` loop:

```
for f in *.sam; do
    samtools flagstat "$f" >"${f%.sam}.stat"
done
```

Notice the [quotes.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

(If you absolutely want a one-liner, you can replace the newline before `done` with a semicolon.)

Comment: thanks for answer, this is much complicated than my code. I performed it using python loop but I wanted to run in single line:

Comment: my code : `text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(cwd) if f.endswith('.sam')]
        for f in text_files:
            os.system("samtools flagstat " + f +" > " + f.replace(".sam",".stat") )`

Comment: I see no improvement; if you don't need the list again, why would you keep it in a variable? Also, again, the documentation for `os.system` explicitly recommends to use `subprocess` instead. The linked question contains (a lot more) details. The loop will fail if any of the file names require [quoting.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)